# Getting the version of Renesas USB 3.0 Host Controller driver on Windows

Tags: windows, usb

Older versions of the Renesas USB 3.0 Host Controller have issues that may cause problems. To alert my customers of such problems, I need to detect outdated versions. To do this, I want to retrieve the running driver version same as the Renesas USB 3.0 Host Controller Utility does.

Answer (score 0):

With OSR IrpTracker, I've determined the IOCTL and structure. Here's sample code that opens each Renesas USB Host Controller's device interface and queries the version number.

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winioctl.h>

#include <pshpack1.h>

DEFINE_GUID(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NUSB3XHC,              0xac051b02L, 0x603b, 0x4b3c, 0xb1, 0x4b, 0x95, 0xc9, 0x26, 0x8d, 0xe0, 0x81);

struct NUSB3XHC_DRIVER_VERSION
{
    UCHAR Major;
    UCHAR Minor;
    UCHAR Build;
    UCHAR Revision;
    UCHAR Unknown[2]; // no idea what this is -- {0, 0} on my machine
};

struct NUSB3XHC_FIRMWARE_VERSION
{
    USHORT BcdVersion; // UI displays this as BCD
};

#define IOCTL_NUSB3XHC_GET_DRIVER_VERSION CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x800, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

#define IOCTL_NUSB3XHC_GET_FIRMWARE_VERSION CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x808, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

#include <poppack.h>

BOOL GetVersion(LPCTSTR DevicePath, NUSB3XHC_DRIVER_VERSION* DriverVersion, NUSB3XHC_FIRMWARE_VERSION* FirmwareVersion)
{
    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(DevicePath, GENERIC_ALL, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDevice == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD returned;
    if (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_NUSB3XHC_GET_DRIVER_VERSION, NULL, 0, DriverVersion, sizeof(NUSB3XHC_DRIVER_VERSION), &returned, NULL))
    {
        success = (returned == sizeof(NUSB3XHC_DRIVER_VERSION));
    }

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_NUSB3XHC_GET_FIRMWARE_VERSION, NULL, 0, FirmwareVersion, sizeof(NUSB3XHC_FIRMWARE_VERSION), &returned, NULL))
    {
        success = success && (returned == sizeof(NUSB3XHC_FIRMWARE_VERSION));
    }

    CloseHandle(hDevice);

    return success;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int crap = IOCTL_NUSB3XHC_GET_FIRMWARE_VERSION;

    HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NUSB3XHC, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devIfaceData;
        devIfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

        DWORD Index = 0;

        do
        {
            if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NUSB3XHC, Index, &devIfaceData))
                break; // hopefully ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS

            DWORD requiredSize;
            SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &devIfaceData, NULL, NULL, &requiredSize, NULL);
            // returns with ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA devIfaceDetailData =
                (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) malloc(requiredSize);
            devIfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &devIfaceData, devIfaceDetailData, requiredSize, NULL, NULL))
            {
                NUSB3XHC_DRIVER_VERSION driverVersion;
                NUSB3XHC_FIRMWARE_VERSION firmwareVersion;
                if (GetVersion(devIfaceDetailData->DevicePath, &driverVersion, &firmwareVersion))
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("%s: driver version: %d.%d.%d.%d, firmware version: %x\n"), devIfaceDetailData->DevicePath,
                        driverVersion.Major,
                        driverVersion.Minor,
                        driverVersion.Build,
                        driverVersion.Revision,
                        firmwareVersion.BcdVersion);
                }
                else
                {
                    _tprintf(_T("Failed getting version data from %s.\n"), devIfaceDetailData->DevicePath);
                }
            }

            free(devIfaceDetailData);

            ++Index;
        }
        while(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```